# Custom Url Rewriting in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

can anyone please provide me the details how we can implement custom URL rewriting in `asp.net`

My current url is look like below :

```
www.domainname.com/News/default.aspx?newstitle=todays latest news
```

And now I would like to redirect to below url :

```
www.domainname.com/News/todays-latest-news
```

Please suggest me how we can achieve the same.

Comment: Refer to:\ http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 1):

Add this to global.asax

```
using System.Web.Routing; //top of the page

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "news/{news}", "~/news/default.aspx");
}
```

And then you can get the news title in default.aspx like below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.RouteData.Values.Count > 0)
    {
        string newstitle = this.RouteData.Values[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to achieve your task use the concept called asp.net routing ,
here is the few examples refer for better understanding

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/77199/URL-Routing-with-ASP-NET-4-0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use URLRewriter.Net for this purpose. It's very easy to integrate into asp.net project and also it's open source . Add the dll file of urlRewriter.Net into your project and set the rewriting rule in your web.config file. Although be careful when using it with ajax postback pages. In Raw url if you get ajax postback problem .